# Service Worker - Image Caching

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I use my Service Worker to cache some images using Ajax GET function to the URL of the image I want to cache in order to be able to display this image in the future without being online.

At some point in my project , I need to create an Image constructor instance and pass the URL of a cached image as a source. When I do this, the response of `caches.match(event.request).then((response)` is always null.

If anyone has any idea why will be very helpful!

Comment: Can you provide some more information, including potentially a link to a live reproduction? When I've seen strange cache misses in the past, it's usually been due to the presence of a `Vary:` header, and you can work around that by passing `{ignoreVary: true}` as the second parameter to `caches.match()`. But it's hard to diagnose without more info.

Comment: It actually worked well by adding this parameter! To be honest I had no idea about this response header. As far as I understand , because the image I'm trying to request has response header `Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers` , and the Image constructor has different headers with the GET request , the Service Worker was not giving me a match in the cache. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's the default behavior of `match()`, but you can override it with `ignoreVary`. If there's a `Vary:` header, it will only return a match if the request you pass in adheres to the vary logic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary

Answer (score 2):

*(Moving this from the comments.)*

This sounds like it's due to the presence of a `Vary:` header on your requests. By default, the [vary logic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary) will apply to the Cache Storage API's `match()`, which can lead to "mysterious" cache read failures.

Setting the [`ignoreVary: true` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match#parameters) when calling `match()` is a way of opting-out of this logic, and just matching based on URL.